# What's the meaning of "mean" in "in the mean time"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

As I understand it "in the mean time" means "in the time between now & a specific future occurrence."  **What's the meaning of "mean" here?**

I assume it has something to do with "average" but it's not clear to me exactly what.

Comment: Not so much 'average' as 'middle' or 'between'. _In the meantime_ is an idiomatic phrase that refers to the time remaining for action between one event and a later event. 'Average' is a modern meaning; but note that it's the middle of a distribution, any way you graph it. Also related to 'common', 'normal', and 'prototype'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *mean* in *meantime* and *meanwhile* does, as you suspect, come from the same root as the word meaning mathematical average.

The original meaning of this *mean* is *middle*, and, with respect to *meantime*, it branches off to meaning *intermediate* and then further off to mean<sup>1</sup>:

> Intermediate in time; coming or occurring between two points of time or two events; intervening

The mathematical meaning also comes from this *middle* meaning, but branches off into a meaning of *average, middling* or *moderate*, which is then co-opted by maths.

1. "mean, adj.2." OED Online. Oxford University Press, December 2014. Web. 26 January 2015.

Answer (score 1):

[Meantime / Meanwhile « The Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2012/01/meantime-meanwhile/)

> The “mean” in “meantime” and “meanwhile” is the adjective “mean” meaning “occurring between two points in time,” based on the noun “mean,” middle point, from the Latin “medianus,” in the middle. (This is a separate word from the other adjective “mean” in the sense of “nasty,” which comes from Germanic roots meaning “common, low-quality.” And the verb “to mean” in the sense of “to connote” or “to intend” comes from yet other roots meaning “to tell or say.”) The “while” in “meanwhile” is the noun form of the word, meaning “a period of time,” thus serving the same function as the “time” in “meantime.” We also use “while,” of course, as an adverb meaning “at the same time” (“While the cat’s away, the mice will file a restraining order”).